# Looking to show all the name of the mat-tree-node (Angular material2)

Tags: angular, angular-material2

My tree is in a div (`height = 30%` of the screen). My tree has three level and I can not read the all name of the third level. (the name is cut).

Anyone knows how I can "`break-word`" or add a scroll in my mat-tree (`overflow-x: scroll` does not work)?

I tried :
`overflow-wrap: break-word; overflow-x: scroll; width: auto`

When I write `width: auto` in my css file, it doesn't change anything : I can't see the entire name of all the node.

Thanks a lots !!

Comment: Please provide a Stackblitz, so we can try it out by ourselves.

Comment: are you adding the `overflow` to the div containing the `mat-tree`?

Comment: Thanks @Lados   !! This is a Stackblitz link to present my case : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ogxlgz

Comment: Yes I tried @JasonWhite  but it changes nothing ! This is a Stackblitz link to present my case : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ogxlgz  ,Thanks !

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: Seems like this is a known issue with checkboxes: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/11889. As of now it is still open.

Answer (score 0):

In your tree-checklist-example.css

Add this CSS:

```css
.mat-tree-node {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

For every tree node you will get a scrollbar when it's too long.

Here's a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ogxlgz-vpwa7f?file=app/tree-checklist-example.css)